# Rails transform_values just one key[value]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below hash of hashes

```
answers = {"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "answer"=>"0" },
"1"=>{"id"=>"2", "answer"=>"0" },
"2"=>{"id"=>"10", "answer"=>"0" },
"3"=>{"id"=>"11", "answer"=>"0" },
"4"=>{"id"=>"12", "answer"=>"0" },
"5"=>{"id"=>"13", "answer"=>"0" },
"6"=>{"id"=>"7", "answer"=>"0" }}
```

Now I want to replace `'answer'` value to real answer. To do so I could use below map:

```
correct_answers = answers.map { |key, value| AppropriatenessTestQuestion.find(value['id']).answers[value['answers'].to_i] }
 => ["Yes", "No", "Don't know", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]
```

But how to replace the hash value of the key `answer` by '<correct_answers>' in the same order to have a expected hash as given below:

```
answers = {"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "answer"=>"Yes"},
"1"=>{"id"=>"2", "answer"=>"No"},
"2"=>{"id"=>"10", "answer"=>"Don't know"},
"3"=>{"id"=>"11", "answer"=>"Yes"},
"4"=>{"id"=>"12", "answer"=>"Yes"},
"5"=>{"id"=>"13", "answer"=>"No"},
"6"=>{"id"=>"7", "answer"=>"Yes"}}
```

I was trying to use `transform_values`:

```
answers.transform_values { |value| AppropriatenessTestQuestion.find(value['id']).answers[value['answers'].to_i] }
```

But instead of the whole hash I only get the following:

```
 => {"0"=>"Yes", "1"=>"Yes", "2"=>"Yes", "3"=>"Yes", "4"=>"Yes", "5"=>"Yes", "6"=>"Yes"}
```

Comment: `"But how to replace the hash value 'reply' by 'correct_answers' in the same order?"`
Didn't get you here on this line.

Comment: I'm not getting you on hash value, `answer` is a key not value.
Do you want to change the key from `answer` to `correct_answers`.

All the answers in your raw data is having "0" value. don't know what are other possible values.
and how you are getting this result.

`["Yes", "No", "Don't know", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]`

Comment: @HirenBhalani question updated, should be clearer

Comment: The values in your hash are again hashes, so each `value` in `transform_values` is a hash. You have to return the entire (modified) sub-hash from the block, not just its `"answer"` value. Something like `answers.transform_values { |hash| hash.merge('answer' => new_value) }` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will replace:
`"answer"=>"0"` with `"answer"=>"Yes"` and return updated answers hash

```rb
answers.each do |_, value|
  value['answer'] = AppropriatenessTestQuestion
                      .find(value['id'])
                      .answers[value['answers'].to_i]
end
```